# looking for a sql without union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table with 3 columns: id, status and time_created.

Now I want to grab the ids from 2 different subsets, and here is my current SQL look like.

```
select id from (
(select id from table1 where status in ( 1,2,3) and time_created > sysdate - 5 ) 
union 
(select id from table1 where status in ( 4, 5,6)
);
```

But I want to keep this SQL string shorter. So does anyone know, if I am not using "union", there is a different way to do that ?

Thanks,

Chun

Answer (score 3):

This should help -

```
select id 
from table1 
where ( status in ( 1,2,3 ) and time_created > sysdate - 5 ) 
   or ( status in ( 4,5,6 ) )
```

Comment: Maybe you should include `distinct` op doesnt say anything about source table but in original query duplicate are removed during union.

Comment: `id` sounds like a probable primary key, so I don't think adding `distinct` makes sense here.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I know maybe isnt necesary but `distinct` make sense. Worst case doesnt alter result Best case give exact result as union. Thas was the comment intention.

Comment: I always believed that id's are ment to be primary key - or at least unique - so I'm not used to type distinct when selecting id.. But you made a good point, the op should take notice.

Comment: I suspect the OP doesn't realise the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

In this case a simple OR of the two conditions should work.

```
select id from table1 where (status in ( 1,2,3) and time_created > sysdate - 5 ) OR  status in ( 4, 5,6)
```